# React-native: Is it possible to use pure Flux with React Native and not its implementations like Redux etc.?

Tags: react-native, flux, expo, reactjs-flux

I was trying to get familiarized with **React Native** by doing a very simple project using React Native. I wanted the code to be clean and following some architecture. I've been using **Flux with React** for some time now and thought I could do the same with **React Native** as well. If I am wrong here , kindly let me know why is it not possible?

Assuming that I was correct, let me present the actual problem that I am facing. I am following the **CRNA** tutorial and using **Expo** to build and test. To follow **Flux** architecture. This is what I had done.

Installed Flux with `npm install flux`

Created a `dispatcher.js` file with the following code.

```
import { Dispatcher } from 'flux';
export default new Dispatcher();
```

Created a 'sampleactiondispatcher.js' that does:

```
import Dispatcher from '../actiondispatchers/dispatcher';
import ActionType from '../actiondispatchers/actiontype';

class SampleActionDispatcher  {

    saveSomething(value) {
       Dispatcher.dispatch({
         actionType: ActionType.SAMPLE_ACTION, 
         payload:  value
       });
    }
}
export default new SampleActionDispatcher();
```

Created a store which has a registered a callback to the dispatcher`samplestore.js`

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';
import Dispatcher from '../actiondispatchers/dispatcher';
import ActionType from '../actiondispatchers/actiontype';

// Constants
const SAMPLE_EVENT = 'SampleEvent';

class SampleStore extends EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        super();        
        // Registering the callback
        Dispatcher.register(this.dipatcherCallback.bind(this));
    }

    dipatcherCallback(action) {
        switch (action.actionType) {
            case ActionType.SAMPLE_ACTION:
                this.emit(SAMPLE_EVENT);
                break;
        }
    }
}
export default new SampleStore();
```

Here is the component that fires the action `samplecomponent.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet,
    Dimension, 
    TextInput, 
    View, 
    Text, 
    Button,
    KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native';
import SampleActionDispacther from '../../actiondispatchers/sampleactiondispatcher';

let screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

export default class SampleComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            textValue: ''
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <KeyboardAvoidingView id='sampleComponentHolder' style={styles.editorContainer} behavior='padding' enabled>
                <View id='formFieldsHoldder' style={{paddingTop: 20}}>
                    <TextInput
                        id='textField1'
                        style={[styles.textStyle, styles.input]}
                        underlineColorAndroid = 'transparent'
                        placeholderTextColor='rgba(14,194,145,1)'
                        placeholder='Enter something'
                        keyboardType='numeric'
                        value={this.state.textValue}
                        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({textValue: text})}
                    /> 
                    <Button
                        id='saveButton'
                        color='rgba(46,107,138,1)'
                        title='Save'
                        onPress={this.onPressingSaveButton}
                    />                  
                </View>  
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        );
    }   

    /**
     * On pressing the save button
     */
    onPressingSaveButton =() => {
        if (this.state.textValue !== '') {            
            SampleActionDispacther.saveSomething(Number(this.state.textValue));
        } else {
            alert('Oops! I dont think you have provided any values for saving.');
        }
    }
}

// Styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    editorContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'column',
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    textStyle: {        
        color: 'rgba(14,194,145,1)',
        fontFamily: 'monospace',
        fontSize: 16,
        textAlign: 'center'
    },
    input: {
        height: 40,
        width: (90 * screenWidth)/100,
        borderWidth: 1
     }
});
```

The real problem which makes me think that Flux is not working with react native is that, **whenever I click the save button the dispatched action is not reaching the store.** It would be really helpful if anyone can figure out why this is happening. Or is anything wrong with the code that I 've written?